# How to pack 2D boxes with nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm

I am developing a web app with node js and I need to use a box packing algorithm to find the optimal solution. I could try to do an algorithm myself (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problems) but I was wondering if anything like this already exists? Any idea?

Currently I have a array of objects that look like this.

```
var box = [
    {info: 'some info', width:200, height: 50},
    {info: 'some info', width:200, height: 50}
];
```

And I would like to have the (x,y) coordinates, to know where to pack every box into a 2D space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the [backpacking node js module](https://github.com/paulfournel/backpacking/) (I am the developer) that may do what you need.

## Example

You can pass any list of object as long as they have `height` and `width` attribute defined. Here is a short example:

```
var BackPack = require("backpacking");

var boxes = [];
for(var i = 0; i<20; i++){
    var width = Math.floor(Math.random() * (20 - 5 + 1)) + 5;
    var height = Math.floor(Math.random() * (20 - 5 + 1)) + 5;
    boxes.push({info: 'box_'+i, 'width': width, 'height': height});
}

// Define the width and the height of the container where you want to pack your boxes.
backPack = new BackPack(40, 10000);

// Here you have the packedBoxes with de x and y coordinates.
packedBoxes = backPack.pack(boxes);
```

## Disclaimer

The solution is not optimal. But it is a fast algorithm. The quality of the packing should be improved in the next month.

## More Info

Have a look at the github.com README for more details https://github.com/paulfournel/backpacking/